# How do I unhook this connector?

Tags: light-fixture, connectors

See attached image. It's for a light kit for a ceiling fan. I have a new light kit--how do I disconnect this? [image]

Comment: With the power off at the breaker, should just need to push in on the locking tabs and pull apart.

Comment: That's easier said than done, but I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: try turn and pull, or just pull

Comment: It looks like twist lock